# How to simplify this fraction $\frac{x^2+7x+1}{x^2-4}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, rational-functions

I'm familiar with polynomial long division but I keep getting stuck when I try to answer this question. Online math calculations also say there's no way to simplify this (but it's a homework question so there must be?) If anyone can understand this, please explain how they reach their answer!

$$\frac{x^2+7x+1}{x^2-4}$$

Comment: Do you want a partial fraction decomposition? What do you mean by simplify?

Comment: What's the problem with polynomial division? Just do the first step. The polynomial $x^2+7x+1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z[x]$, so it cannot be simplified.

Comment: @PeterForeman It just says "Simplify" and then the above fraction. The course level is between high school and college. I know it's not very helpful - I'm confused too. It's a question compulsory as part of a distance learning qualification I'm doing and the course layout/guidance is very poor (it was also cheap so that's prob why). Even so, do you have any recommendations how I could answer this?

Comment: There is only one way: there is a typo. The original question asks to simplify $\frac{x^2+7 x+10}{x^2-4}$ which can be factored as $\frac{(x+2) (x+5)}{(x+2) (x-2)}$ and finally gives $\frac{x+5}{x-2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the polynomial $P(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is irreducible, where $$ P(x) = {x^2 + 7x + 1} $$

We need to show this at first.

$\bullet~\textbf{Proof:}~$ On the contrary, let's assume $P(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\exists~a_{1}, a_{2} \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$ x^2 + 7x + 1= (x - a_1)(x- a_2) = x^2 -(a_1 + a_2)x + a_1 a_2 $$
Hence, on the coefficient comparison, we have that $$a_{1}a_2 = 1 \quad \text{and} \quad a_{1} + a_{2} = -7$$
As $a_{1}, a_2 \in \mathbb{Z}, $ then $a_{1} = a_2 = 1$ or $a_{1} = a_2 = - 1$. But as $a_{1} + a_{2} = -7$, it's not possible!

Hence, we arrive at a contradiction!

Therefore, $P(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}.$

As $P(x) \not\equiv 0 \pmod{Q(x)}$ where $Q(x) = (x - 2)(x+ 2) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Then the fraction $$ \frac{x^2 + 7x + 1}{x^2 - 4}  $$
is not simplifiable.

---

$\blacksquare~$**Edit:** I just saw in the comment section, that the polynomial fraction is
$$ \frac{x^2 + 7x + 10}{x^2 - 4} = \frac{(x + 2)(x + 5)}{(x + 2)(x - 2)} = \frac{(x-5)}{(x-2)} $$

Comment: Thank you for this response. I agree, there must be a typo in the question. If not, your proof has helped me understand why it can't be simplified! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome @secretagentsky